# Оптимизировать программу на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import itertools
mas = []
k = int(input())
d = { 'I': 1,
      'V': 5,
      'X': 10,
      'L': 50}
v = 0
z = 0
for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('IVXL', k):
    for x in ''.join(i):
        z = z + d[x]
    mas.append(z)
    z = 0
print(len(set(mas)))
```

Comment: `''.join(i)` тут лишнее, можете просто по кортежу `i` итерироваться. И `mas` можно сразу сделать `set`, а не список и `add` туда делать

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```py
import itertools

k = int(input())

mas = set()
d = {
    'I': 1,
    'V': 5,
    'X': 10,
    'L': 50,
}

for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('IVXL', k):
    mas.add(sum(d[x] for x in i))
print(len(mas))
```

---

Однако, **если я правильно понял его смысл**:
Посчитать количество чисел, которые можно записать из римских цифр `IVXL` по `k` цифр в числе, то ваш код **неверен**.
Они работают не просто как сумма. Например, `IV` = `4`, а не `6`, как посчитает ваш код.